# Networking a POE VOIP phone and a non-POE router with one Ethernet port

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, switch, power-over-ethernet

I'm wiring up an office with one available Ethernet wall jack. The jack currently services a VOIP phone that is powered over the Ethernet cord and has no normal plug. I need to set up a small network behind a (non-POE) router to be running off the same jack, but if I plug the router into the wall jack then the VOIP phone line can't be powered through the router's ethernet out jacks.

The only other switches and hubs I have available are all non-POE. I'd like to find the most cost efficient way to wire both of these devices into the network. Most of the POE-enabled switches I see on the market have 8+ jacks, which is overkill for connecting a single device.

I've seen a few smaller POE hubs and splitters on the market, but I don't know if these will work in this situation. What is the best device to install given these parameters?

Answer (score 1):

You can get AC->POE adapters that add power to a single Ethernet line to power a single POE device.

They are known as [POE injectors](http://poeinjector.com/), and several manufacturers make them.

Comment: I did run across those, and they seem like the best option (although needing to wire up another power cord is an annoyance). Do you know if they make basic 4-port hubs that can pass-through PoE from the wall jack? It would be much easier to just put one of those between the router and the jack.